# How to properly adjust text alignment when input language changes (LTR / RTL) while editing HTML contents with UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

This appears to be automatic for UITextField and UITextView. When text is empty, if you change the keyboard to RLT languages like "ar" and "he-IL", the cursor goes to the right-most position. When you change the keyboard to other languages, the cursor goes to the left-most position. For UIWebView, the cursor is always at the left-most position regardless of the selected input language (device primary language is LTR).

I can force RTL or LRT text alignment by setting dir attribute for HTML on detecting keyboard input language changes, like:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.dir='rtl'"]
```

or

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.dir='ltr'"]
```

This is effective but appears to be applying to the entire content. Apple native mail does a better job and only the alignment for the current text line/paragraph is affected by this. I am not sure whether Apple native mail is implemented with UIWebView though.

I am looking for suggestions/hints so that I can mimic the Apple native mail HTML editing behavior (with RTL language support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the CSS property "direction" to the specific html element in the page you want to change. 
As for knowing when the user switched language in the iOS keyboard  you can listen to the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` notification

And this will give you the current language:

```
[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage
```